# Redirect loop in Laravel when migrating existing codebase

Tags: php, laravel

I have a web-app with an existing codebase which I'm trying to slowly migrate to Laravel. I have setup some of the existing sites URL structure inside the Laravel public directory, so if there's an existing physical directory or file in there it will execute these files, and then I plan to set up routing in app/routes.php for the URLs I want Laravel to handle.

This works okay if I call a URL directly such as this - http://ttm.presencehosting.net/test/index.php

The problem is if I leave off the index.php e.g. http://ttm.presencehosting.net/test/ - this sets the browser into a redirect loop. (I have no routes setup for 'test', it's an actual folder). Ideally I'd like both URLs to execute the code in app/public/test/index.php

Can anyone help with how to stop the redirect loop?

Comment: The problem is probably in your `.htaccess` file.. Could you show it to us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

When you try to access a directory in your public directory, this rule takes action, creating a redirection loop.

You can avoid this by adding a condition to check if the directory already exists:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Beware the 301 redirects, they are annoyingly cached!
Also, check if this will not 'corrupt' any of your existent routes.

Hope that helps!